# Inserting image in example

Tags: graphics

Here is my tex-code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[yyyymmdd]{datetime}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}{
  enhanced,
  sharp corners,
  attach boxed title to top left={
    yshifttext=-1mm
  },
  colback=white,
  colframe=blue!75!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  boxed title style={
    sharp corners,
    size=small,
    colback=blue!75!black,
    colframe=blue!75!black,
  } 
}{thm}
\newtcbtheorem[no counter]{Example}{Eksempel}{
  enhanced,
  sharp corners,
  attach boxed title to top left={
    yshifttext=-1mm
  },
  colback=white,
  colframe=blue!25,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  coltitle=black,
  boxed title style={
    sharp corners,
    size=small,
    colback=blue!25,
    colframe=blue!25,
  } 
}{prf}


\begin{document}

\section*{Funktioner}

\subsection*{Hvad er en graf?}

\noindent En \textbf{graf} er billedet af en funktion, som man tegner ind i et koordinatsystem.  \\

\begin{Example}{}{}
\noindent Vi ønsker, at tegne grafen for funktionen $y=4\cdot x$. Denne funktion beskriver sammenhængen mellem $x$ og $y$. Vi vælger først forskellige $x$-værdier og finder deres $y$-værdier: \\
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline
$x$ & $y$  \\ \hline
0 & 0  \\
1 & 4  \\
2 & 8  \\ 
3 & 12  \\ 
4 & 16  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\noindent Ved at bruge $x$ og $y$-værdierne kan vi nu tegne grafen (billedet) af funktionen $y=4\cdot x$:
\end{Example}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
 \centering
  \includegraphics[width=4cm]{billede.png}
  \label{fig:boat1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I would like my image to be inside the example-box but latex keeps showing an error. How do I fix this?

[image: billede]

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but `\label{fig:boat1}` won't work because the figure does not have a caption.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your image inside the example box, you should not use a `figure` environment, because a figure environment allows your image to "float" through your document, which is contra productive if you want it at a specific place.

In case you might want a caption for your image, you could use the `\captionof` macro from the `caption` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[yyyymmdd]{datetime}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}{
  enhanced,
  sharp corners,
  attach boxed title to top left={
    yshifttext=-1mm
  },
  colback=white,
  colframe=blue!75!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  boxed title style={
    sharp corners,
    size=small,
    colback=blue!75!black,
    colframe=blue!75!black,
  } 
}{thm}
\newtcbtheorem[no counter]{Example}{Eksempel}{
  enhanced,
  sharp corners,
  attach boxed title to top left={
    yshifttext=-1mm
  },
  colback=white,
  colframe=blue!25,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  coltitle=black,
  boxed title style={
    sharp corners,
    size=small,
    colback=blue!25,
    colframe=blue!25,
  } 
}{prf}


\begin{document}

\section*{Funktioner}

\subsection*{Hvad er en graf?}

\noindent En \textbf{graf} er billedet af en funktion, som man tegner ind i et koordinatsystem.  \\

\begin{Example}{}{}
\noindent Vi ønsker, at tegne grafen for funktionen $y=4\cdot x$. Denne funktion beskriver sammenhængen mellem $x$ og $y$. Vi vælger først forskellige $x$-værdier og finder deres $y$-værdier: \\
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline
$x$ & $y$  \\ \hline
0 & 0  \\
1 & 4  \\
2 & 8  \\ 
3 & 12  \\ 
4 & 16  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\noindent Ved at bruge $x$ og $y$-værdierne kan vi nu tegne grafen (billedet) af funktionen $y=4\cdot x$:

\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}
\end{Example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Welcome in TeX.SE.

The error comes from the float environment `figure`. Floats may not to be inside any fixed environment as `example` in your example. You can simply remove the figure environment and add:

```
\begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=4cm]{billede.png}
\end{center}
```

at the end of your example environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[yyyymmdd]{datetime}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}{
  enhanced,
  sharp corners,
  attach boxed title to top left={
    yshifttext=-1mm
  },
  colback=white,
  colframe=blue!75!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  boxed title style={
    sharp corners,
    size=small,
    colback=blue!75!black,
    colframe=blue!75!black,
  } 
}{thm}
\newtcbtheorem[no counter]{Example}{Eksempel}{
  enhanced,
  sharp corners,
  attach boxed title to top left={
    yshifttext=-1mm
  },
  colback=white,
  colframe=blue!25,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  coltitle=black,
  boxed title style={
    sharp corners,
    size=small,
    colback=blue!25,
    colframe=blue!25,
  } 
}{prf}


\begin{document}

\section*{Funktioner}

\subsection*{Hvad er en graf?}

\noindent En \textbf{graf} er billedet af en funktion, som man tegner ind i et koordinatsystem.  \\

\begin{Example}{}{}
\noindent Vi ønsker, at tegne grafen for funktionen $y=4\cdot x$. Denne funktion beskriver sammenhængen mellem $x$ og $y$. Vi vælger først forskellige $x$-værdier og finder deres $y$-værdier: \\
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline
$x$ & $y$  \\ \hline
0 & 0  \\
1 & 4  \\
2 & 8  \\ 
3 & 12  \\ 
4 & 16  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\noindent Ved at bruge $x$ og $y$-værdierne kan vi nu tegne grafen (billedet) af funktionen $y=4\cdot x$:


\begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=4cm]{billede.png}
\end{center}

\end{Example}

\end{document}
```

Comment: a `figure` is float environment as well a `table` is. both should not be included in any box...

Comment: @Zarko yes, you are right. My answer mentions otherwise ? I can edit to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: i took liberty and extend your explanation in you answer  with my comment (instead of you).

Comment: @Zarko feel free to edit it. I just wonder what i wrote wrong in my answer about the floating environments.
I mentioned precisely that the figure environment is not compatible with environments like example.
Maybe i had to be more precise in the future ? Thanks !